# How to write a customized gradle task to not to ignore Findbugs violations but fail after the analysis is completed

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I want to write such a gradle task (using the *Findbugs* plugin) which fails if any *Findbugs* violations are found **but only after completing the analysis**. If I do `ignoreFailures=true` the task won't fail at all and if I make it false the task fails as soon as the first issue is found. I want the task to perform a complete analysis and fail only after it's done if any violations are found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, adding `ignoreFailures=true` will prevent task from failing. Thus this option *should* be used and it should be checked later on if bugs were found.

This script does the job:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

findbugs {
   ignoreFailures = true
}

task checkFindBugsReport << {
   def xmlReport = findbugsMain.reports.xml
   def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlReport.destination)
   def bugsFound = slurped.BugInstance.size()
   if (bugsFound > 0) {
      throw new GradleException("$bugsFound FindBugs rule violations were found. See the report at: $xmlReport.destination")
   }
}

findbugsMain.finalizedBy checkFindBugsReport
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28069712) complete and working example can be found. To see if it works remove `incorrect.java` file - then no bugs are found and - no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Violations Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-gradle-plugin) for this. Then you can also run checkstyle, or any other analysis, before the build is failed.

```
task violations(type: se.bjurr.violations.gradle.plugin.ViolationsTask) {
 minSeverity = 'INFO'
 detailLevel = 'VERBOSE' // PER_FILE_COMPACT, COMPACT or VERBOSE
 maxViolations = 0

 // Many more formats available, see: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib
 violations = [
  ["FINDBUGS",   ".", ".*/findbugs/.*\\.xml\$",   "Findbugs"]
 ]
}

check.finalizedBy violations
```