# Findbugs Gradle plugin won't fail the build

Tags: gradle, static-analysis, findbugs

I'm trying to use findbugs plugin in my build.gradle file in order to fail the developers personal build but it's not working.
Although the plugin creates the reports the build won't fail. 
I have tried to 'play' with the **ignoreFailures** property but that didn't go well either.

I used this answer [How to write a customized gradle task to not to ignore Findbugs violations but fail after the analysis is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069712/how-to-write-a-customized-gradle-task-to-not-to-ignore-findbugs-violations-but-f), and it worked but I don't like to parse the reports and it feels like a hack.

Is there no simple way (like 'ignoreFailures' should be) to fail the Gradle build using findbugs? Is there another suitable framework to do that?

Added the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.1"
    }
}

subprojects {
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin:'eclipse'


apply plugin: "findbugs"
findbugs {
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
}

build.dependsOn 'check'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version:'1.1.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: "${VERSION_SPRING_SECURITY}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: "${VERSION_SPRING_SECURITY}"

    // Spring dependency injection container:
    compile (group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:"${VERSION_SPRING}") {
        exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }

    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version:'1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.10'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.7.10'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.7.10'
    runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:"${VERSION_ASPECTJ}"
    runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version:"${VERSION_ASPECTJ}"

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:"${VERSION_SPRING}"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'



    compile group: 'commons-pool', name: 'commons-pool', version:'1.6'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.5.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-mrbean', version:'2.5.1'

}
}

project(':server:application'){
dependencies {

    compile(project(':server:services')) {
        exclude(module: ':server:data-access')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:"${VERSION_SPRING}"
    compile project(':server:dto'), project(':server:utils'), project(':server:model')
}
}
```

Comment: Findbugs is not failing at all. even when the ignoreFailures = false (though its the default)

Comment: Could you provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Added the build.gradle file

Comment: Well, ok, but where's the project to try? It seems that there's nothing wrong with the build.gradle itself.

Comment: What do you mean with 'project to try'? all the sub projects (like server:application etc.) are the projects to try... if i got you right...

Comment: I mean a sample project on the web that reproduces the problem. Now it can be whatever :/ Without sample code that reproduces the problem it might be problematic to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the issues Findbugs finds are not "high priority" bugs, they won't be reported as you're explicitly setting:

```
reportLevel = "high"
```

The [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) is clear about that:

> The priority threshold for reporting bugs. If set to low, all bugs are reported. If set to medium (the default), medium and high priority bugs are reported. If set to high, only high priority bugs are reported.

So, my recommendation is to do this in your findbugs configuration:

```
ignoreFailures = false
reportLevel = "low"
```

That does work for me.